# Using multiple ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol, what does it try first?

Tags: c#, .net, https

In .NET 4.5, if I set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to multiple protocols and the server accepts all of these protocols, which protocol will be used to make the request?

Does it start with the highest protocol and fail back or does it start with the simplest protocol and fail forward?

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: I've not looked into this too much, but the article here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx mentions that .Net 4.6 will attempt to use the most secure behavior first.

Comment: Ill make it an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not looked into this too much, but the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol) mentions that .Net 4.6 will attempt to use the most secure behavior first. From the looks of things, that is about as good as it's going to get unfortunately.

Comment: incomplete link ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a lot of this is dictated and outlined in the [TLS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1)s.

Connection to a server secured with SSL/TLS requires an exchange of 'Hello' packets in which the browser offers all the TLS protocol versions it can use, along with all the cipher suites and other TLS extensions it can utilize.  The server then chooses which of these protocols, ciphers and extensions will be used and tells the client.

When the client and server converse about the protocols and ciphers, they are listed in order of preference.  The preference is most secure to least secure.  I couldn't find in the RFC if the server is *required* to choose the most secure protocol that it supports, but this is a generally accepted norm.

This may help:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168390/how-is-the-tls-version-selected-between-client-and-server